# Update on 2 tables with one to one relation ship

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables user and technician with one to one connection, technician inherits from user. After editing technician information through edit form and saving, no update happens on tables user and technician; and no errors as well.

Here is my code:

**controler**

```
public function edit($id)
{
$techniciens=technicien::find($id);
$user = $techniciens->user;
return view('technicien.edit',['techniciens'=>$techniciens])-
>with('user',$user);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
// do some request validation

$technicien=technicien::find($id);
$technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
$user->update($request->all());

$technicien->update($request->all());
return redirect('/technicien');
}
```

**view**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $techniciens-
        >techniciens ) }}" method="update">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('post') }}
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nom">Nom</label>
            <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" 
            value="{{$user->nom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="prenom" value="{{$user->prenom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" 
            value="{{$user->tel}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobil" 
            value="{{$user->mobil}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="role" 
            value="{{$user->role}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Email</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" 
            value="{{$user->email}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Email</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="password" value="{{$user->password}}" >
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
            <input type="text"name="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" 
            value ="{{$techniciens->moyenne_avis}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
            <input type="text"  name="actif" class="form-control" value ="
            {{$techniciens->actif}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="enregistrer" class="form-control btn 
           btn-primary">
        </div>
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/tache/{id}/edit', 'TacheController@edit');
Route::patch('/tache/{id}', 'TacheController@update')->name('tache.update');
```

**model1**

```
 <?php

 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
protected $guarded = [];
public function technicien()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\technicien');

}

use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password','nom','prenom','tel','mobil','role',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

**model 2**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class technicien extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
    'moyenne_avis', 'actif',
];
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = [];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function zoneintervention()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\zoneintervention','technicien_zone','technicien_id','zoneint
ervention_id');

}
    public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier','technicien_id','metier_id');

}
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\tarificationtache','technicien_tarificationtache','technicie
 n_id','tarificationtache_id');
}


}
```

Comment: `$user->nom = $request->update($request->all());` what does this line do?

Comment: Check your models, user and technician. The update() method requires a $fillable variable that contains an array of column names that can be mass assigned.

Comment: I added the models, thank you to check

Comment: Do this at update method in the Controller,
`$technicien->update($request->all());
$technicien->save();`